# Suppose $I \subset A$ is an ideal. Show that $f$ vanishes on $V(I)$ if and only if $f \in \sqrt{I}$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Suppose $I \subset A$ is an ideal. Show that $f$ vanishes on $V(I) = \{[\mathfrak{p}] \in \operatorname{Spec} A \mid I \subset \mathfrak{p} \}$ if and only if $f \in \sqrt{I}$.

So since we know that $\sqrt{I} = \bigcap_{I \subset \mathfrak{p}}\mathfrak{p}$ it's sufficient to show that $f$ belongs to each prime ideal containing $I$. Now we also know that $f$ vanishes on $V(I)$ that is for all $[\mathfrak{p}]$ we have that $f([\mathfrak{p}]) = 0$.

Now the way I've understood that we define the value of $f \in A$ for $[\mathfrak{p}] \in \operatorname{Spec} A$ is essentially that we consider $f \pmod{\mathfrak{p}}$. So if $$f \equiv 0 \pmod{\mathfrak{p}}$$ this would imply that $f$ is in each of the prime ideals containing $I$ yielding the proof?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The main point is translating geometric language into algebraic language, which you've done.